# CSS file is not read in php index and header

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create two php pages : header and index. i created them in html and defined the style of them. Now i am trying to turn them into php files. So i created the files and copied the content of each html file into them. and put the css file link into the head of each file. But while testing i do not get any css properties from what i defined.

I have tried to coppy the while path of the css file but it doesnt work either.

Heres the index code :

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Velo pour tous</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
</head>


<body>
    <?php 
    include 'templates/common/header.php'
    ?>
    <div class="acceuil-block">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Bienvenue dans le site officiel de l'association des enthousiastes de vélos</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <form>
                <label for="">Choisissez une date :  </label>
                <input type="date" id="start_date_interval">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sep"></div>
    <div class="sep"></div>
    <div class="acceuil-summary">
    <h1>Découvrez notre association</h1>
    <div class="sep"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column left">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="stores.png">
            </div>
            <h2>Qui-sommes nous ?</h2>
            <p class="paragraphe_index">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, sem eu mollis malesuada, magna dolor tempus diam, vitae auctor odio magna in felis..</p>

        </div>
        <div class="column middle">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="icon (3).png">
            </div>

            <h2>Ce nous vous proposons</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, sem eu mollis malesuada, magna dolor tempus diam, vitae auctor odio magna in felis.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="column right">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="business-card-of-a-man-with-contact-info.png">
            </div>
            <h2>Contactez-nous</h2>
            <p class="paragraphe_index">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum, sem eu mollis malesuada, magna dolor tempus diam, vitae auctor odio magna in felis.</p>

        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="footerNom">Vélos pour tous</div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

The header.php file :

```
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Velo pour tous</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Projet tech web ratt/css/app.css">


<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="C:\wamp64\www\Projet tech web ratt\ressources\logo.png">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/ab/Documents/test%20projet/Qui%20sommes%20nous.html">Qui-sommes nous ?</a></li>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/ab/Documents/test%20projet/ce%20que%20nous%20vus%20proposons.html">Ce que nous vous proposons</a></li>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/ab/Documents/test%20projet/login.html">Connexion</a></li>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/ab/Documents/test%20projet/contact.html">Contactez-nous</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <hr>
    </header>
</body>

</head>
</html>
```

And the css file (i put it just to show the selectors and give you an idea of the style) :

```
*{
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Century Gothic;

}

header{
    height:15vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

ul{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 25px;

}

li a{
    display : block;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color : #000;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.acceuil-block{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(file:///C:/wamp64/www/Projet%20tech%20web%20ratt/ressources/logo.png)
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}


ul li.active a{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.logo img{
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: auto;
}

.main{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin :auto;

}


.title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.title h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 62%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff; 
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;

}

.button:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.sep{
    margin: 30px;
}

.acceuil-summary h1{
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
/* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left, .right, .middle {
    text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
}
.left, .right{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.row{
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column h2{
    margin: 20px 0px;

}
.paragraphe_index{
    margin-top: 49px;
}

footer{
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 65px;
}

/************************Qui Sommes nous************************/
.image_quiSommesNous{
    background-image:url(../videoblocks-group-of-young-happy-cyclists.png);
    height:70vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.cadre_quiSommesNous{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 900px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 15%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.cadre_quiSommesNous h1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.cadre_quiSommesNous p{
    margin: 20px;
}
.footer_quiSommesNous{
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
.footerNom_quiSommesNous{
    line-height: 65px;
    color: #fff;
}

/********************ce que nous vous proposons********************/

.sep{
    background-color: black;
}

.inscription{
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    position: absolute;
}

.inscription:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

/********************login********************/

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {

  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6 ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #000;

}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}

/*contact*/

form textarea{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Here is also the hierarchy of my project :

C:\wamp64\www\Projet tech web ratt

```
 -file : css

       app.css

 -file : ressources

       all the images i am using

 -file : templates

       header.php


 and the index.php (that is not in any of those files)
```

i want to also point out that neither of the images i imported is shown

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show us the error message found in console of browser

Comment: here it is : https://imgur.com/a/bv01bq4

Comment: 404 means that file not found. Try to check if your directory again, if the files exist try to use `\` instead of `/` in identifying directory

Comment: so from what I see here I can assume that the issue is with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/app.css">` you are going out of to many directories, based on what did you show. Just remove one `../` in this line and check it

Comment: It worked, i simply put css/app.css in the path. however im still struggling with an image im trying to import as a background-image in the css file. I made the directory ../ressources/velobar-m_3hlP5WcC0-unsplash.jpg and the browser says that its been loaded however it is not shown. Heres an image of how the page should look vs how how the page looks now : https://imgur.com/a/3hVVjon

Comment: On a side note, it looks like you're producing invalid HTML. Your header file duplicates the `<head>` and `<body>` tags. If I understand you correctly, then header should be a _partial_ file, right? The CSS file should be defined in your index file only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then header.php should be a *partial* file, right? The CSS asset should be defined in your index file only.

Based on your directory structure, this should work:

- Since the header file is in a directory at the same level as your index file, you can simply reference is as `templates/common/header.php`
- Since header.php is a partial file which will be injected in the main body you shouldn't duplicate HTML tags such as `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Velo pour tous</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <?php include 'templates/common/header.php'; ?>
    ...
```

**header.php**

```
<header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="logo">
                <!-- You should be able to reference your assets like this -->
                <img src="ressources/logo.png">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                <!-- I intentially left out your file pointer because I don't know your directory structure for these -->
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <hr>
    </header>
```

**EDIT**

As for the image which you're referencing in your CSS, I assume you mean `videoblocks-group-of-young-happy-cyclists.png`. It helps to think about these things as if **you're physically standing in the file that is currently being run**. So, if your directory structure is:

```
css/app.css 
ressources/*
```

then, when the CSS file is being processed, you would need to jump up 1 directory and then into the `ressources` directory in order to reference an image.

Like so:

```
.image_quiSommesNous{
    background-image:url(../ressources/videoblocks-group-of-young-happy-cyclists.png);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your template file and your header have `head` tags. This is invalid HTML. You should have two header files.

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Velo pour tous</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
  <?php 
  include 'templates/common/header-head.php'
  ?>
</head>


<body>
  <?php 
  include 'templates/common/header-body.php'
  ?>
  <!-- everything else -->
</body>
```

header-head.php:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Velo pour tous</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Projet tech web ratt/css/app.css">
```

header-body.php

```
<header>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="C:\wamp64\www\Projet tech web ratt\ressources\logo.png">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/ab/Documents/test%20projet/Qui%20sommes%20nous.html">Qui-sommes nous ?</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/ab/Documents/test%20projet/ce%20que%20nous%20vus%20proposons.html">Ce que nous vous proposons</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/ab/Documents/test%20projet/login.html">Connexion</a></li>
            <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/ab/Documents/test%20projet/contact.html">Contactez-nous</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<hr>
</header>
```

Comment: Looking at the paths for your css files I suspect that this also might be incorrect. I would stick to using absolute paths for your files, or use a `<base>` tag to define your relative base path and use relative paths from that.